# Do Killing vector fields satisfy $\nabla_a X^a + \nabla_b X^b=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Killing vector fields are those that verify $\mathcal{L}_X (g)=0$. This is equivalent to the following equation for a coordinate basis:

$$\nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b X_a=0$$

Do Killing vector fields satisfy $\nabla_a X^a + \nabla_b X^b=0$? I was wondering today if this happens but I wasn't able to prove or disprove it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested equation reduces to $\nabla_a X^a = 0$ since $\nabla_a X^a = \nabla_b X^b$. Your suggested equation is also correct, since $$\nabla_a X^a = \nabla_a \left(g^{ab}X_b\right) = g^{ab}\nabla_a X_b$$ is a contraction of a symmetric tensor with an antisymmetric one.

Comment: Intuitively this is true because $\nabla_a X^a$ is the rate of change of volume when you flow in the direction $X$, but the flow of Killing fields are isometries.